# Tortoise-ORM: How to query a Postgres `ArrayField` from tortoise.contrib.postgres.fields

Tags: python, orm, fastapi, tortoise-orm

Just created a Postgres `ArrayField` in Tortoise-ORM via `from tortoise.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField` to host some tags I wish to put. Looking at my Postgres db the generated  field is indeed of type `text[]` which is good but how exactly do I query it using the Tortoise Query API?

I've tried several attempts at using `filter` but each one either returns an empty list or raises an error.

**Table**

```
+----+---------------+
| id | tags (text[]) |
+----+---------------+
| 1  | {foo,bar}     |
+----+---------------+
| 2  | {foo}         |
+----+---------------+
| 3  | {bar}         |
+----+---------------+
```

```py
# End results

# Works but uses: CAST("tags" AS VARCHAR) LIKE '%foo%'
await Card.filter(tags__contains='foo').values_list('id', flat=True)   

# Doesn't work
await Card.filter(tags__search=['foo']).values_list('id', flat=True)     # error
await Card.filter(tags__search='foo').values_list('id', flat=True)       # error
await Card.filter(tags=['foo']).values_list('id', flat=True)             # error
await Card.filter(tags='foo').values_list('id', flat=True)               # error
await Card.filter(tags__in=['foo']).values_list('id', flat=True)         # []
await Card.filter(tags__in='foo').values_list('id', flat=True)           # []
```

Also tried it using `set` or `tuple` but the results are the same.

#### Update

I haven't been able to find a way to query an `ArrayField` in TORM so I'm using `JSONField` instead which has much better support.

```py
# Old
tags = ArrayField('text', null=True)    # can't query for now

# New
tags = JSONField(default=[])
```

I will keep this question here in case someone else has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was also considering using JSONField, although in Postgres Array field is a bit more flexible in some cases. I found [this comparison in DBA community](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/279996/when-to-use-json-or-jsonb-array-vs-sql-array-in-postgres).

I ended up implementing my own typed ArrayField: [How to use Postgresql Array field in Tortoise-ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64161083/how-to-use-postgresql-array-field-in-tortoise-orm)

In your case, I suppose, you will need to implement your own filter operator for array contains.
I would check out existing filters for an example: [default filters](https://github.com/tortoise/tortoise-orm/blob/develop/tortoise/filters.py) and  [contrib Postgres filters](https://github.com/tortoise/tortoise-orm/blob/develop/tortoise/contrib/postgres/json_functions.py).

Here is how contains operator looks in PostgreSQL itself: [Postgres: check if array field contains value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39643454/postgres-check-if-array-field-contains-value)

Hope this is somehow helpful :)

Comment: andnik my thoughts exactly on the filters. I've never created a custom one before so this should be fun. Will try to do it over the weekend if my cat hasn't killed me yet.

Comment: hahaha, let me know how this goes. maybe I'll give it a try as well